# How Hibernate pooling works if pooling size is less than concurrent connections?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, c3p0

I am using Hibernate with c3p0 as pooling provider. I have set its max size as 50 only. Now, I performed load testing of my application with 1000 concurrent threads accessing database continuously and with mysql max_connections as 2000. I am getting proper responses from the application but sometimes I face socket exception error.

So, first thing is if my pooling size is 50 only, how 1000 connections are managed by hibernate ? Does it mean that 50 connections are being taken from the pool and rest of the connections are created? Also, why I must be getting socket exception like connection reset exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you've set things up properly and c3p0's maxPoolSize is 50, then if 1000 clients hit the pool, 50 will get Connections initially and the rest will wait() briefly until Connections are returned by the first cohort. the pool's job, in collaboration with your application which should hold Connections as briefly as possible, is to ensure that a limited number of Connections are efficiently shared.

if you are seeing occasional connection reset / socket exception, you probably ought to configure some Connection testing:

http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/index.html#configuring_connection_testing

the latest prerelease version has some more direct advice about connection testing; you can download that or read the html source starting here:

https://github.com/swaldman/c3p0/blob/master/src/doc/index.html#L1071

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have seen that link before but I am not able to figure out which setting to go for to avoid socket exception. I don't get any exception when number of threads are 100 but when I make it to 1000, I start getting exceptions. Socket exceptions are due to network issue, as I have read. Does it mean that for a single processor, it is difficult to manage 1000 concurrent continuous connections?

Comment: might be possible, might not. if you post your config, i'll comment on connection testing.